# Check if list1 contents matches list2 contents

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 lists with some data in:

```
List1.Add(new Filter { Name = "Foo", Value = "Bar" });
List2.Add(new Filter { Name = "Foo", Value = "Bar" });
```

I would like to use Linq to return true if `List1` contains ALL the values in `List2`, the example above would obviously return true but this is an example but if I added

```
List2.Add(new Filter { Name = "Foo1", Value = "Bar1" });
```

then it should return false.

I started going down the lines of:

```
var Result = from item1 in List1
             join item2 in List2 on item1.Name equals item2.Name
             new { item1, item2 };
```

but this would only match on the Name and I'm pretty sure I am going down the wrong route with this.

**EDIT**: Just to clarify, I don't want only the VALUE property. Name && Value must match in both lists.

Comment: Do you care about duplicates? E.g. if `List2` contains two `Foo/Bar`s but `List1` only contains one, do you still want `true` to be returned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx):

```
var l1Vals = List1.Select(f => f.Value);
var l2Vals = List2.Select(f => f.Value);
var notInL1 = l2Vals.Except(l1Vals);
if(notInL1.Any())
{
    // no, not all Values of List2 are in List1
}
```

**Edit** According to your last edit that you want to compare all properties of `Filter`, the best approach is to create a custom [`IEqualityComparer<Filter>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) and use that as argument for this [`Enumerable.Except` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390.aspx):

```
public class Filter {
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Value { get; set; }

    public class Comparer : IEqualityComparer<Filter>
    {
        public bool Equals(Filter x, Filter y)
        {
           if(ReferenceEquals(x, y))
               return true;
           else if(x==null || y==null)
               return false;
           return x.Name  == y.Name
               && x.Value == y.Value;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Filter obj)
        {
            unchecked 
            {
                int hash = 17;
                hash = hash * 23 + obj.Name.GetHashCode();
                hash = hash * 23 + obj.Value.GetHashCode();
                return hash;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now this works:

```
var notInL1 = List2.Except(List1, new Filter.Comparer());
if (notInL1.Any())
{
    // no, not all properties of all objects in List2 are same in List1
    // notInL1 contains the set difference
}
```

Comment: it just check one property not other

Comment: @alliswell: That's what OP wants: _"ALL the values in List2"_. `Value` is a property of the `Filter` class. Except determines the set difference. That is all `Values` of `List2` that or not in List1' `Values`.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. Name and Value must match in both lists (bad choice of words). I have updated my post.

Comment: This appears to be working at the moment. I am just going to test a few scenarios before marking as an answer.

Comment: Ok, the previous confusion with it only matching on value is causing problems. Can you adapt this to match on Name && Value?

Comment: @webnoob: However, i would rollback your last edit since it introduces new classes which is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
bool areAllElementsInList2 = list1.All(i => list2.Contains(i));
```

The Contains-Methode uses the Equals-Methode to specify wether a item is in that list or not. So you should override the Equals-Methode of Filter-Class.

Or you try:

```
bool areAllElementsInList2 = list1.All(i1 => list2.Any(i2 => i1.Name == i2.Name && i1.Value == i2.Value));
```

HTH Tobi

Comment: `Filter` is a class and not a primite type. You need to select the `Value` property since that is what OP has asked for.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. Name and Value must match in both lists (bad choice of words). I have updated my post. Also, I tried this example but it always returns false even when I manually enter the same information into both lists.

Comment: I have just updated my post with my latest example. Still returning false unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool list1doesNotContainAllFromList2 = list2.Except(list1).Any();
```

Note that if you need working with sets - comparing etc., it would be better to use `HashSet<>` collection instead of `List<>` - it has methods like `ExceptWith` or `UnionWith` that will perform faster than standard LINQ operators.

Comment: I've not downvoted but: `Except` with custom classes does work only if you implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode` or pass a custom `IEqualityComparer<T>`. However, OP wants to compare only the `Value` property.